# It is possible to show a route between two POINTS selecting the type of transport?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm showing a route between two points with this code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+lastLocation.getLatitude()+","+lastLocation.getLongitude()+"&daddr="+(double)point.getLatitudeE6()/1000000+","+(double)point.getLongitudeE6()/1000000));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");           
    startActivity(intent);
```

This code works perfectly, but I need to add to that code the possibility to select for example, public transport. It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

In your Uri, you can add one more parameter to select type of transport:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+lastLocation.getLatitude()+","+lastLocation.getLongitude()+"&daddr="+(double)point.getLatitudeE6()/1000000+","+(double)point.getLongitudeE6()/1000000 + "&dirflg=r"));
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", 
            "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));          
    startActivity(intent);
```

dirflg = h for driving,
dirflg = r for public transport,
dirflg = w for walking directions.

Transit Mode (public transport) will be displayed only if available for that region, otherwise MapActivity will show a toast for its non-availability and will show directions for driving (motorways).

Comment: this way doesn't shows me the map directly, shows the indications with text. It is possible to show directly the map?

Comment: not works, the same issue, it shows the indications instead of the map

Comment: I have tested it on 3.2 and 4.0.4 , it is showing map instead of text. Which version you are testing on ? Have you tried by changing intent.setClassName with intent.setComponent line ? Is your google map uptodate ?

Comment: i tested this in android 2.2. Also i tested in cyanogen mod 9 and the app crashes and gives me this error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.xtreme.iSenegal/java.util.Map}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?